# Inputs Automaticos

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax

Hola tengo el siguiente código:

```js
  function combus() {
     let input1 = Number( document.getElementById('input1').value );
     let input2 = Number( document.getElementById('input2').value );
     let op = input1 * 4 * 2 * input2;
     
     document.getElementById('res1').value = op;
  }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
                 <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Distancia aproximada desde origen (KM)</label>
                 <input type="number" class="form-control" id="input1" onkeyup="combus()" placeholder="KM aproximados">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Unidades necesarias</label>
                 <input type="number" class="form-control" id="input2" onkeyup="combus()" min="0" placeholder="Número de unidades">
               </div>
               
               <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fas fa-gas-pump"></i></span>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="res1" readonly>
                </div>
```

Funciona bien, pero me salio la idea de querer sumar el resultado que me da en res1, lo cual se refiere a que si creo otra función de la misma manera con diferentes inputs como sumaria el resultado de res1 y res2 (ejemplo asi se llamaria el otro resultado donde se va a imprimir) cual seria la manera correcta de hacerlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se podría activar mediante el clik de un botón que sume los valores, creo que así comprendí, espero te sirva de algo.

**Edición:** *(Sugerencia por Usuario Miguel)* Ya no se usa el botón para calcular la suma de las dos respuestas, ahora se llama el método `total()` en cada método `combus()`, de esta forma queda dinámico al momento de escribir los valores en los *inputs*

```js
function combus() {
  let input1 = Number(document.getElementById('input1').value);
  let input2 = Number(document.getElementById('input2').value);
  let op = input1 * 4 * 2 * input2;

  document.getElementById('res1').value = op;

  total();
}

function combus2() {
  let input1 = Number(document.getElementById('inputOtro1').value);
  let input2 = Number(document.getElementById('inputOtro2').value);
  let op = input1 * 4 * 2 * input2;

  document.getElementById('res2').value = op;

  total();
}

function total() {
  let res1 = Number(document.getElementById('res1').value);
  let res2 = Number(document.getElementById('res2').value);
  let tot = res1 + res2;

  document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Distancia aproximada desde origen (KM)</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="input1" onkeyup="combus()" placeholder="KM aproximados">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Unidades necesarias</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="input2" onkeyup="combus()" min="0" placeholder="Número de unidades">
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fas fa-gas-pump"></i></span>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="res1" readonly>
</div><br><br>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Distancia aproximada desde origen (KM)</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputOtro1" onkeyup="combus2()" placeholder="KM aproximados">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Unidades necesarias</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputOtro2" onkeyup="combus2()" min="0" placeholder="Número de unidades">
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fas fa-gas-pump"></i></span>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="res2" readonly>
</div><br><br>

<b>Total:</b><input type="text" id="total" readonly>
```

Comment: excelente me funciono amigo, gracias

Comment: Una duda si el resultado me da decimales como lo redondeo antes de mostrar el resultado ? y ya de ahi mostrar el numero redondeado

Comment: Vale, me alegro que te haya funcionado. En cuanto al redondeo, puedes usar `Math.round()`, este método redondea el número dependiendo si el decimal es mayor o menor a `.5`, entonces podrías hacer así: `document.getElementById('total').value = Math.round(tot);`